# AWS ECS Task Slow Processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, ecs-taskdefinition

I am using AWS to deploy my python project by using docker. I choosed FARGATE for task definition and Task Memory is 512, Task CPU is 256.

There is a process that takes too much time on AWS. It takes 1 second on my PC(i7-6700HQ and 16.0 GB ram) and 13 seconds on AWS.

Do you know how can i fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Increase Fargate specs to match similar to your PC - what other answer is there? What were you looking for?

Comment: I didn't think the problem is specs. Because the process is not hard so much. I will try this if there will be not another suggestion. I don't want to be charged more.

Comment: Are **all** requests slow or only the first one after a while?

Comment: I can't try too much, because there is another problem. It is spamming 404 error (Because trying "GET / HTTP/1.1" itself) and shutting down everytime then returning 503 to me. Maybe I should open new question for this.

Comment: @YagizTurkmen sounds like you have / configured as the healthcheck endpoint but didn't configure your service to return 200 for the healthcheck. I would not expect a crashlooping service to perform well...

Comment: @jordanm yes I asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69569914/aws-ecs-service-fastapi-project-is-spamming-get-http-1-1-404-not-found?noredirect=1